# How to convert an array of objects in an array of integers extracting values from those objects using ramda.js?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm trying to convert an array of objects into an array of integers extracting values from those objects using Ramda.js. I need to keep just the node **participants** with the uid values, however, it seems that I'm not doing this correctly.

I'm want to transform this

```
var listObejcts = {
  "participants": [
    {
      "entity": {
        "uid": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "entity": {
        "uid": 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "participants": [1, 2]
}
```

I've tried the code above but it didn't work. It's still returning a list of objects.

```
var transform = pipe(
  over(lensProp('participants'), pipe(
    filter(pipe(
      over(lensProp('entity'), prop('uid'))
    ))
  ))
)

console.log(transform(listObejcts))
```

Does anybody know how I could achieve that?

It's possible to edit the code here - https://repl.it/repls/PrimaryMushyBlogs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to combine [`evolve`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) with [`map`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/map)([`path`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path)) like this:

```js
const transform = evolve({participants: map(path(['entity', 'uid']))})

var listObjects = {participants: [{entity: {uid: 1}}, {entity: {uid: 2}}]}

console.log(transform(listObjects))
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script><script>
const {evolve, map, path} = ramda  </script>
```

While I'm sure that there is a lens-based solution, this version looks pretty straightforward.

### Update

A `lens`-based solution is certainly possible.  Here is one such:

```js
var transform = over(
  lensProp('participants'), 
  map(view(lensPath(['entity', 'uid'])))
)

var listObjects = {participants: [{entity: {uid: 1}}, {entity: {uid: 2}}]}

console.log(transform(listObjects))
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script><script>
const {over, lensProp, map, view, lensPath} = ramda  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Also could use just pure JavaScript es6:

`const uidArray = listObjects.participants.map(({ entity: { uid } }) => uid);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it in Ramda, but you can simply use [VanillaJS™](http://vanilla-js.com/) for that and have a fast, one-line, library-free solution:

```js
const obj = {
  participants: [
    {entity: {uid: 1}},
    {entity: {uid: 2}}
  ]
}
obj.participants = obj.participants.map(p => p.entity.uid);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Just so you know, someone looking for a Ramda solution probably is not interested in a technique that modifies the input.  Of course this could easily be fixed up not to do that.

Comment: I don't really know the philosophy of Ramda, thanks for the input! I just went for the simplest solution that fitted the OP's requirements

Comment: to fit the Op's requirements you needed to use ramda... Mutating the input is non an option in fp.